# MySQL Join multiple rows into one field

Tags: mysql

Currently I have a database with two tables zip_codes and emails. zip_codes contain the three fields zid, eid, and zip. emails contain eid, email, and location.

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT a.zid, a.zips, b.email, b.location FROM zip_codes AS a INNER JOIN emails AS b ON a.eid = b.eid
```

Basically what I want to do is to transform the results I get into this (http://sqlandme.com/2011/04/27/tsql-concatenate-rows-using-for-xml-path/), but I'm not sure at all how to do this with my current set up.

I tried changing the names but I get error in my syntax near [text()] and since I have no idea how to use this, i'm stuck.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Does your emails have morethan one zip code and you want the all the zip codes with each email as a list ?

Comment: There are anywhere from 10 to 80 zip codes all going to one email. I would like to get a single row for each email and location that has all the zip codes separated by commas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Mysql you can use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT 
  b.email,
  b.location,
  GROUP_CONCAT(a.zips) zipcodes 
FROM
  zip_codes AS a 
  INNER JOIN emails AS b 
    ON a.eid = b.eid 
GROUP BY b.eid
```

> Note for using [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by
>   the group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value of
>   1024. The value can be set higher, although the effective maximum length of the return value is constrained by the value of
>   max_allowed_packet